# Missing nodes when trying to parse xml in php

Tags: php, xml, feed

I am using the following feed: http://feeds.livep2000.nl/

I try to parse it with the following line of code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($url), null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

It shows me data like i expect but missing the `geo:lat` and `geo:long` like this:

**XML**

```
<item>
<title>
<![CDATA[
A2 (DIA: ) some title
]]>
</title>
<link>http://monitor.livep2000.nl?SPI=1707082033480217</link>
<pubDate>Sat, 08 Jul 2017 20:33:48 +0200</pubDate>
<description>
<![CDATA[
1420999 MKA Rotterdam-Rijnmond ( Monitorcode )<br/>1420029 MKA Rotterdam-Rijnmond ( Ambulance 17-129 )<br/>
]]>
</description>
<guid>1707082033480217</guid>
<author/>
<geo:lat>51.8431255</geo:lat>
<geo:long>4.3429498</geo:long>
</item>
```

**Response**

```
    ["item"]=>
        array(50) {
          [0]=>
              object(SimpleXMLElement)#163 (6) {
                ["title"]=>
                string(41) "some title"
                ["link"]=>
                string(48) "http://monitor.livep2000.nl?SPI=1707082036240209"
                ["pubDate"]=>
                string(31) "Sat, 08 Jul 2017 20:36:24 +0200"
                ["description"]=>
                string(44) "description ( Ambulance 09-129 )"
                ["guid"]=>
                string(16) "1707082036240209"
                ["author"]=>
                object(SimpleXMLElement)#213 (0) {
                }
              }

etc....
```

Any idea why the geo nodes are missing?

Comment: These nodes are in `geo` namespace. Read about namespaces in XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `lat` and `long` are a part of `geo` namespace in the mentioned XML and `simplexml` does not allow you to access them by default.

You need to use something like:

```
$ns = $xml->getNamespaces(TRUE);

foreach ($xml->channel[0]->item as $item) {
    var_dump($item->children($ns['geo'])->lat);
    var_dump($item->children($ns['geo'])->lon);
    // do other stuff with $item here
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick, never heard of namespaces in xml before. Nice to know!

Comment: But you should not read the namespaces from the document, just define an array of them. The namespace prefixes in the document can change and are optional.